# Fitting a square grid with non-overlapping rectangles

Tags: algorithm, tiling

Let R be a list of rectangles R<sub>i</sub> with integer height h and width w.

What are all the possible positions of these rectangles and their 90 degree rotations on a NxN square grid (N <= 64) without overlaps? Every rectangle R<sub>i</sub> can and must be placed only once, but there can be duplicates in the list R. (You could also say each rectangle has to be placed m<sub>i</sub> times, where m<sub>i</sub> is a natural number bigger than 0, so no duplicates in set R)

#### For example

Let R = {{1, 2}, {1, 1}}.

And a 2x2 square grid:

```
0 0
0 0
```

We can fit the rectangles in the following way, where 'a' represents the first rectangle and 'b' the second rectangle:

```
b a    0 b     a 0    a a    
0 a    a a     a b    0 b    

0 a    b 0     a b    a a    
b a    a a     a 0    b 0
```

The bigger picture is finding the best tiling in respect to a metric. I'm still thinking about the exact metric, its about the distance between some of the edges of the rectangles. I thought spanning the solution space would be a good start for some algorithm, greedy search or neural net etc.

Comment: Hi. Just a note about vocabulary: "cover" is a term very often use to say "we want every point to be covered by at least one object, and we don't care if objects overlap". What you want here is the opposite, I would word it as "fit a square grid with non-overlapping rectangles".

Comment: thank you, english isn't my first language, i corrected it

Comment: It's more about a domain-specific convention than about general English language :-) What kind of answer are you looking for? A python script that bruteforces the answer? A reformulation of the problem as an assignment problem or as integer programming or constraint programming? A theoretical analysis of the complexity of the best algorithm?

Comment: Finding the best (in some sense) position is called a 2D cutting-stock problem and to say that "it gets complicated" is an understatement. Finding *all* positions is just crazy. What would you do with all the positions? There easily could be trillions of them for a modestly sized instance of the problem.

Comment: The bigger picture is finding the best tiling that minimizes a certain metric. I'm still thinking about the exact metric but has to do with the distance between the edges of the rectangles. I thought spanning the solution space would be a good start for some algorithm, maybe a neural net of some sorts. We can restrict N to 64 for now if that makes the problem easier.

Comment: @Stef Getting to know how big the solution space gets would be a good start. :)

Comment: Maybe OR-Tools ' CPSAT solver's constraint `AddNoOverlap2D(x,y)` can help.